# Import Express Routes causes Request Body to be Undefined

Tags: node.js, express, httprequest, body-parser

I am using express to build a mongodb + auth0 app.

My requests maintain their body when they are placed in index.js, but as soon as I move into another js file in the project, it returns undefined, where headers and other req attributes are maintained.

### index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const port = 8000;

var loginRoutes = require('./routes/login');

app.use(express.json());

const clientPromise = require('./mongodb-client');

app.use('/login', loginRoutes);
```

### /routes/login.js

```
const express = require('express')
router = express.Router();

const clientPromise = require('../mongodb-client');

const auth0 = require('../auth0-client');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const {ObjectId} = require("mongodb");

//LOGIN USER
router.post('/', async function(req, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));

    var data = {
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
      };

     auth0.passwordGrant(data, function (err, userData) {
        if (err) {
          // Handle error.
        }
      
        console.log(userData);
      });

    res.send({'login': 'yes'})
})

module.exports = router;
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with express.json() and maybe some OOO issue? But I'm drawing on the search engines and can't figure out what to troubleshoot next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.use(express.json());` must come before `var loginRoutes = require('./routes/login');` for the request body to parse and be successfully passed to the child login route.